# Повторение паттерна фона определенное количество раз

Tags: css, background

Есть свойство `background: url("some-img.png") repeat-x`.Нужно, чтобы элемент `some-img.png` повторялся по оси `х` не до конца родительского блока, а определенное количество раз( например -  5 раз по горизонтали). Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант - [multibackgrounds](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multibackgrounds)

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(http://www.graycell.ru/picture/small/romb.jpg), url(http://www.graycell.ru/picture/small/romb.jpg), url(http://www.graycell.ru/picture/small/romb.jpg), url(http://www.graycell.ru/picture/small/romb.jpg), url(http://www.graycell.ru/picture/small/romb.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0, 100px 0, 200px 0, 300px 0, 400px 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: У меня не отображается

Comment: Новый Google Chrome

Comment: Приверил работает в Chrome Версия 55.0.2883.87 m (64-bit) Win7

Comment: Оу, обновил страницу - заработало. Но согласитесь, вариант не кроссбраузерный

Comment: Поддержка браузерами - http://caniuse.com/#feat=multibackgrounds

Comment: Убедили :) +1..

Answer (score 1):

Есть такой костыльный вариант с созданием фона внутренним элементом:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
div:before {
  display:block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  content: '';
  background-image: url(http://www.graycell.ru/picture/small/romb.jpg);
  background-size: 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```